# Android svg file click on each path

Tags: android, svg, vector

I'm using a svg map and I need to click on each province and give some information about that province. 
Is it possible to make click method for each path ???

Comment: As far as I know. The only solution for this, at the moment, is to load the SVG into a WebView.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau That's what I thought but i hoped there were some way for that , thank you anyway